# Not null value from one thread, is null in another one

Tags: java, multithreading, vert.x, blockingqueue

I am working on a multi-client TCP server in Java. As the server must be able to perform a lot of simulaneous operations, I created a thread, used to send data to my client, through the socket. It's defined as follow :

```
public class MessageSender implements Runnable{

    private OutputStream output;
    private volatile ArrayList<byte[]> messagesToSend;

    public MessageSender(OutputStream _output)
    {
        output = _output;
        messagesToSend = new ArrayList<byte[]>(0);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
           if (messagesToSend.size() > 0)
           {
               sendMessage(messagesToSend.get(0));
               messagesToSend.remove(0);
           }
        }
    }

    public void setMessageToSend(Message message)
    {
        messagesToSend.add(message.getMessageHandler().getBytes());
    }

    public void sendMessage(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes == null)
        {
            System.out.println("bytes = null");
            return ;
        }
        try
        {
            output.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The class `Message`, that you can see in `setMessageToSend()`, is a class of mine. I also have created other classes (`Channel_test`, `Channel_status`), corresponding to specific messages, and that inherit from `Message` class.

I have another thread, in which I create a `Channel_status`, as follow :

```
eventBus.consumer(msg + port , message -> {
    sender.setMessageToSend(new Channel_status(eParameters));
    channel_test = new Channel_test(eParameters);
    System.out.println("Created Message");
});
```

This is a `Vertx` handler, that is only called once, when receiving a specific message from the client. It is called, and channel_status is instansiated as expected. In this same thread, I have a Vertx timer, in which I send a byte array contained by my channel_status class, to the `MessageSender`.

```
vertx.setPeriodic(duration, id -> {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(channel_test.getMessageHandler().getBytes()));
    sender.setMessageToSend(channel_test);
});
```

As you can see, I am printing it's value to make sure it is not null. And, it's never null in the timer. But when the MessageSender receives it, sometimes it is null (by sometimes I mean approximately 1/50 times). Why? Is it a concurrency issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making `ArrayList<byte[]>` `volatile` [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549628/java-volatile-synchronization-on-arraylist) gurantee that when you add new element in thread1, thread2 can see it.

You should use a list that support [concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203864/choosing-the-best-concurrency-list-in-java), such as :

```
messagesToSend  = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<byte[]>(0));
```

This can make sure when you add new element by `setMessageToSend`, the new element will be visible in `run` method.

### Update:

`Collections.synchronizedList` still can not gurantee thread safe in this case. Since in `run` method, the three operations are not atomic.

```
if (messagesToSend.size() > 0)
{
    sendMessage(messagesToSend.get(0));  
    messagesToSend.remove(0);
}
```

A [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) can solve this problem:

```
private BlockingQueue<byte[]> messagesToSend;

public MessageSender(OutputStream _output) {
    output = _output;
    messagesToSend = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            sendMessage(messagesToSend.take());  // this will get blocked untill the queue is not empty
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}

public void setMessageToSend(Message message) {
    try {
        messagesToSend.put(message.getMessageHandler().getBytes()); // put new element in the queue, check if run method is blocked, wake it up
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: wait and notify still needed for less cpu cycle in the while loop

Comment: @HemantPatel Yes, `wait` and `notify` is needed. And I think a `BlockingQueue` is more clean than call `wait` and `notify`.

Comment: One question though. BlockingQueue is an abstract class, and cannot be instantiated right? Maybe I should use LinkedBlockingQueue?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `run` method as

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized(messagesToSend) {
           while (messagesToSend.isEmpty()) {
               messagesToSend.wait();
           }
        }
        sendMessage(messagesToSend.get(0));
        messagesToSend.remove(0);
   }
```

}

And `setMessageToSend()` as

```
public void setMessageToSend(Message message) {
    messagesToSend.add(message.getMessageHandler().getBytes());
    messagesToSend.notify();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't wait and notify be called in two different threads?

Comment: `setMessageToSend` is called via another thread, so notify will be called on another thread, while wait is called by another one

Comment: `wait` and `notify` work in `synchronized` method or block